# an error whilst working with react app - Cannot read property 'photo' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created an app that is a clone of flickr. As the user type in the input box it should render the pictures associated with the search value. Unfortunately, when I type it tells me "Cannot read property 'photo' of undefined", but then it kinda works. I really would like this app to work without any bugs. Please see attached the codesandbox.

https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-kare-oqxw5

Comment: `const images = _(results).map(generateURL);` this will solve your problem

Comment: @Manish hey Manish, thanks I will defo try it out! Do you know by any chance why if I type in my input and console log it always shows me a result with one character less? If I type money in my console.log will appear mone

Comment: You are passing `this.state.query` to the parent even before state.query is set to the actual value. setState sets the state at later point of time. so try calling `this.props.onInput(event.target.value);`

Comment: @ArpithaChandrashekara omg yes! thanks! I hope one day it will become a second nature for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make this function like this. First check weather `photo` is present.

```
jsonp(flickrURL, flickrParams, { callback: "jsoncallback" }).then(
   results => {
      console.log(results);
      if(results.photos){

        const images = _(results.photos.photo).map(generateURL);
        console.log(images);
        this.setState({ images: images });
      }
  }
);
```